# Workbook_Open handler not firing in add-in when opening workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have an add-in for Excel that I attempting to use to insert code to automatically rename the workbook if certain criteria are met. When exporting from our repo, all workbooks have the same name which results in 'Excel cannot open two workbooks with the same name at the same time' error happening over and over again. I've gotten the code to work when the user clicks a button in the add-in, but my attempts to do the same by placing the code in the 'ThisWorkbook' section of the addin does not seem to work. Is there a way to do this via the add-in?

Please find my code below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim wbPath As Variant, wbNewname As Variant, newPath As Variant, wbname As Variant
  Dim fileExtension As Variant

  If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "SR.*" Or ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "SR (#).*" And Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path Like "*Content.IE5*" Then

    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    wbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    fileExtension = Right(wbname, Len(wbname) - InStrRev(wbname, ".") + 1)

    wbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    wbNewname = "SR" & Int((465480 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 838588)

    newPath = wbPath & "\" & wbNewname & fileExtension

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newPath

    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set wbPath = Nothing
    Set wbNewname = Nothing
    Set newPath = Nothing
    Set wbname = Nothing
    Set fileExtension = Nothing

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you have to rename the workbook before you open it and the `Workbook_Open` sub runs after you've opened it I don't think this will work

Comment: @CallumDA It would be very sufficient even if it occurred after the workbook opened

Comment: If you're sure, then I must be misunderstanding your problem

Comment: @CallumDA even if the workbook is renamed after opening, it still solves the problem because any experts following it won't have the same workbook name

Comment: You can't rename a file that's opened. Best you can do is save a copy under a different name... which is what your code seems to be doing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - OP could even save open file ("File.xlsx") as a new file ("File Updated.xlsx"), then open that new file ("...Updated.xlsx"), close "File.xlsx", and then delete "File.xlsx" from the computer.  That may be the easiest/best way to do it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I understand that, and that is my goal -- my apologies for being unclear.

Comment: @BruceWayne that's more or less what I'm trying to do, though I hadn't considered the removal aspect- great idea!

Comment: You need to store `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` in a variable prior to the `SaveAs` (e.g., `oldFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName`), and then after saving the copy you can `Kill oldFile` - might run into file locking issues though, especially if path is on a network drive.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for that. The code isn't executing from the addin at all. I used a msgbox to test and nothing happened

Comment: If that code is in an add-in, you're handling the `Open` even *for the add-in itself* (i.e. `ThisWorkbook` *is* the add-in) - you'll want a `Private WithEvents App As Excel.Application` private field, and then you'll want to handle the `WorkbookOpen` event *at application level*. Let me know if you need help doing that.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to better reflect what appears to be the actual problem as per this comment thread - feel free to further [edit] the post, or roll back my edit if that wasn't appropriate. Cheers!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Probably wouldn't hurt to have an accurate title for my problem, eh? Haha! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` is your add-in - its `Open` event fires when *the add-in* file gets opened, not when *any* workbook is opened beyond that point.

What you want is to handle application-level events, more specifically the `WorkbookOpen` event. Add a private `WithEvents` field to your `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private WithEvents App As Excel.Application
```

In the `Workbook_Open` handler (i.e. at startup), `Set` that object reference:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

Now, look near the top of the code pane - there are two dropdowns. The left-hand dropdown is listing all available event providers and interfaces (i.e. `Workbook` since `ThisWorkbook` is a `Workbook` object, but also any `WithEvents` fields and `Implements` interfaces you've defined in that module); select your `App` field.

Then, the right-hand dropdown will list all available events you can handle for `App`. Pick the `WorkbookOpen` event, and the VBE will automatically create a procedure stub with the correct signature for you:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

End Sub
```

In that handler procedure, you can put the code you want to run whenever a workbook is opened in Excel.

Comment: Hey Mathieu, I appreciate your insights. Maybe you can help me find what I'm doing wrong in my code: I'm getting an 'Object block or With block not set' error now. I'm using the exact same code as above

Comment: I'm assuming that means your code is now under `WorkbookOpen`, and still working against `ActiveWorkbook` - change your code to work against the `Wb` parameter instead (that's the workbook that was opened); the event might be firing *before* the workbook is even activated. If it's something else, I'm afraid my telepathic debugging skills are outmatched ;-)

Comment: You were right about that...But now, a new issue enters (dun dun): "Compile error in hidden module: ThisWorkbook. This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application." The [help file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/compile-error-in-hidden-modulemodule-name) did not seem to sort it out. I updated each to be public modules with no change in outcome.

Comment: To be clear: `ThisWorkbook` is a `Workbook` module listed under "Microsoft Excel Objects" in the VBE's *Project Explorer*, right? Not sure what you mean with "public module" there... I don't know what you're doing, but I can assure you that there is no such problem with the solution I'm providing. Maybe post a new question if you can't solve it? Make sure to include enough details (and screenshot, if needed) so that viewers can reliably reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue: when it is checking the wb.name, it is returning the name of the addin's workbook!

Comment: Oh. So the handler is invoked when the add-in is opened, too.... ok try putting `If wb.FullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName Then Exit Sub` at the top of the `WorkbookOpen` handler - that should bail out if the handler is running for the add-in itself.

Comment: Hey Mathieu, it works now. Got the kill function to work too, so the old workbook won't exist anymore either!